# Get CSS computed style during web crawl

Tags: css, web-crawler

Is there a way for me to get an element's computed style from a page source? Or, if not from the page source, some other way? I want to be able to go to a web page and then get all the computed styles (via my code; I'm not talking about opening a browser tab and clicking Inspect element). Right now I'm using Python BeautifulSoup to get and traverse the document. This gets me all the elements and their attributes, but not the css styles. Ideally this would be with Python, but I'm open to using other languages.

(Sorry, if this has been answered before. I looked at several questions and they all seemed to have to do with getting the info either from "inspect element" or from your own personal page using javascript.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look for CssParsers like the following

http://www.modeltext.com/css/index.html

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/CSSParser.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/). I inject a JavaScript script into the page that runs `getComputedStyle`.